# What is the best way to obtain all running processes on Windows from inside of a Docker container?

Tags: c++, windows, docker, process

I am interested in monitoring processes on Windows and running this application inside of a docker container. In order to obtain list of all the running processes I use [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot), however once I run the code inside the Docker Container the list of running processes is significantly smaller.

I am new to docker, so I wanted to ask which folder should be exposed to Docker via --mount command in order to obtain entire list of running processes (e.g. those that are visible inside the task manager).

On Ubuntu it would be something like /proc/ directory, is there an equivalent to this on Windows 10?

Comment: There's no concept or equivalent of `/proc` on Windows.  I'm guessing CreateToolhelpSnapshot is giving you all the processes in that container. Just like invoking the `ps` command on a Linux container only gives you the processes inside the container.  I'm not a container expert - but it seems weird that you'd expect access to internals from the outside host from inside the container.

Comment: And if you invented a way to pipe that data down from host to container, you'd need to continue to go back to the host to do anything useful with those process ids (like restart, terminating, additional API calls, etc...)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have to agree it is a bit reaching what I am trying to do, but I was hoping that there is a way to at least read stuff. I wanted to mount task manager onto docker's one, but the CreateToolhelpSnapshot is probably independent from it, so I was curious from where does the system get this snapshot, and then wanted to expose that to docker via mount.